# How to import xlsx into dynamodb using python and boto3

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to use LinuxAcademy posting of how to import Excel data into DynamoDB but the code posting is two years old and does not work. Any tips or suggestions would be very helpful.

Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow.

I was trying to take an excel spreadsheet and convert it to json then upload to DynamoDB like the posting on LinuxAcademy. The instructions are old and they use three scripts to upload one file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more explicit, share the code you have tried and the specific errors you are getting, please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to create a lambda AWS python function.

The only problem is that it reads in the excel file and converts it to json and the file is too big to ingest into DynamoDB before the 5 minute timeout. I will probably convert it to step functions but this worked for me.

```
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
import pandas as pd

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = "serverless-record-storage-lambda"


def upload_to_dynamodb(report):
    df=pd.read_excel(report)
    df.columns=["APPLICATION", "FORM_NUMBER", "FILE_DATE", "STATUS_DATE", "STATUS", "STATUS_CODE", "EXPIRATION_DATE", "ESTIMATED COST", "REVISED_COST", "EXISTING_USE", "EXISTING_UNITS", "PROPOSED_USE","PROPOSED_UNITS","PLANSETS", "15_DAY_HOLD?" ,  "EXISTING_STORIES", "PROPOSED_STORIES", "ASSESSOR_STORIES", "VOLUNTARY", "PAGES", "BLOCK", "LOT", "STREET_NUMBER", "STREET_NUMBER_SFX", "AVS_STREET_NAME", "AVS_STREET_SFX", "UNIT", "UNIT_SFX", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "CONTRACTORPHONE",
        "COMPANY_NAME", "STREET_NUMBER", "STREET", "STREET_SUFFIX", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP_CODE", "CONTACT_NAME", "CONTACT_PHONE", "DESCRIPTION" ]
    # Clean-up the data, change column types to strings to be on safer side :)
    df=df.replace({'-': '0'}, regex=True)
    df=df.fillna(0)
    for i in df.columns:
        df[i] = df[i].astype(str)
    # Convert dataframe to list of dictionaries (JSON) that can be consumed by any no-sql database
    myl=df.T.to_dict().values()
    # Connect to DynamoDB using boto
    resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
    # Connect to the DynamoDB table
    table = resource.Table('permitdata')
    # Load the JSON object created in the step 3 using put_item method
    for permit in myl:
        table.put_item(Item=permit)

def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        print(record)
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        print(bucket)
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        print(key)
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        upload_to_dynamodb(download_path)



def main():
    handler(event, None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```